# ckeditor within jquery-ui dialog - internet explorer 11 problem with tool dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, ckeditor, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to display a ckeditor within a jquery-ui dialog,
and it works fine - at first sight.

But in IE11, when I click on any tool button which opens a dropdown / selection (e.g. color selection), there's a short flash of the required overlay on mouse-up, but the next moment it's gone.

It works in Chrome and Edge, but currently IE11 is the most important target browser.

jQuery is 1.11, jQuery-UI is 1.11.4, ckEditor is 4.15.1.

---

I found out, the problem only occurs, when dialog is modal.
Here's a sample:

```
function openDialogEditor() {
    var somedialog = document.createElement("div");
    somedialog.id = "somedialog";
    somedialog.innerHTML = '<div id="somediv"><textarea id="someid" name="somename" class="ckeditor" style="height:350px;">Stackoverflow is great!</textarea></div>';
    document.body.appendChild(somedialog);
    
    jQuery(somedialog).dialog({width: '800px', modal: true}).parent().promise().done(function(dlg) {
        CKEDITOR.replace("someid");
    });
}
```

If you change `modal: true` to `modal: false`, the problem is fixed - but the dialog *should* be modal.

My workaround: see answer below.

Comment: Provide a code sample relevant to your question, so others are able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Sure, @tomfrio.
I therefore constructed a simple example, and guess what - the problem doesn't crop up.
There must be some further circumstances I didn't find out yet.
I'll come back with it or communicate the solution.
Thanks so far!

Comment: How about the issue? You can put your solution as an answer and mark it as an accepted answer if you have solved it. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Or you can provide the reproducible code snippet if you haven't solve it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @yu-zhou.
I don't have any solution yet, and I won't be able to do any work on this before next week.

Comment: Never mind. You can come back at any time you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution, working in IE11:

1. Set the dialog to `modal: false`.
2. Add a custom overlay using jquery's css classes.
3. Remove the custom overlay on dialog close.

(My code sample also requires removing the editor for reusing the `openDialogEditor()` function - this of course could also be handled differently.)

---

1 + 2)

```
function openDialogEditor() {
    var somedialog = document.createElement("div");
    somedialog.id = "somedialog";
    somedialog.innerHTML = '<div id="somediv"><textarea id="someid" name="somename" class="ckeditor" style="height:350px;">Stackoverflow is great!</textarea></div>';
    document.body.appendChild(somedialog);
    
    jQuery(somedialog).dialog({width: '800px', modal: false}).parent().promise().done(function(dlg) {
        CKEDITOR.replace("someid");
        dlg.css('z-index', '101').parent().append('<div id="ownOverlay" class="ui-widget-overlay ui-front" style="z-index:100"></div>');
    });
}
```

3. Extend dialog close function:

```
jQuery.widget("ui.dialog", jQuery.ui.dialog, {
    close: function(ev) {
        // remove custom overlay:
        jQuery("#ownOverlay").remove();
        // remove dialog and editor:
        var dlgDiv = jQuery(ev.target).closest('div[role="dialog"]')[0];
        dlgDiv.parentNode.removeChild(dlgDiv);
        
        return this._super(ev);
    }
});
```

---

If you have better solutions, suggestions, improvements: please comment.  :)

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.